# Taking pictures while streaming with motion

Tags: raspicam, motion, picamera

my Raspi uses the original raspicam and motion to stream security footage to my nas. This works great so far.
I now want to additionally take a picture every 1 hour and save it somewhere.
Obviously I can't just put a raspistill command into a cron job because motion would be still blocking the cam. And I don't want to get hacky and start/stop motion every time I take a picture.
Is there a way to do it with motion, or can I somehow tap the motion stream, to get my still picture?

any input is welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

Found out that motion has a Rest-API like interface which can create Snapshots.
build the following crontab and it does what I needed it to do.

```
0 */1 * * * rm /var/lib/motion/* && curl -s -o /dev/null http://pigrow:8080/0/action/snapshot && ping 10.1 -c 3 > /dev/null && mv /var/lib/motion/image* /mnt/nas
```

without the ping it sometimes didn't work, it couldn't move the file, because it wasn't there.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with a solution - I’ve got to sort out a camera for the squirrels in the garden soon! One minor question - is the ping just to create a delay Before the move or ‘wake’ the system up?

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.